# getting blogs from database by specific category

Tags: php, mysql, blogs, categories

I have created a blog system with categories i have two tables in database, table blogs with `blog_id`, `title`, `body`, `category_id` and a second table with columns `category`, `category_id`. To get blogs from all categories i use this code and it works well.

```
  $query = ("SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, category FROM blogs  INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id  ORDER BY  blogs_id desc LIMIT 10");
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die("error:".mysql_error());
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $title = $row['title'];
        $body = $row['body']; 
        $posted_by = $row['posted_by'];
```

And now i want to get blogs by specific category, i used the same query with addition of "`where category=that category`" it didn't work so i tried `category_id` but it too failed. my code was something like this

```
        $query = ("SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, category FROM blogs INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id where category=anycategory ORDER BY blogs_id desc LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: use `'` on where clause. like this `where category= 'anycategory'`

Comment: try to put and existing category with simple quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `'` on `where` clause.

```
$query = ("SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, category 
FROM blogs INNER
JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id 
where category= 'anycategory'
ORDER BY blogs_id desc LIMIT 10");
```

and **make sure there is a table field** call `category` in your table

Comment: aliases and non-ambiguity too

Comment: when I see this, all I think is, here *might* come an Error 1052

Comment: also i would like to know how to select from multiple categories tried like this where category='cat1','cat2' this didn't work then tried where category='cat1,cat2'  but this didn't work too. :(

Comment: @harman use `and`. like this `where category = 'cat1' and category = 'cat2'`

Comment: @harman no ts will works. `select * from temp where category = 'cat1' and category = 'cat2'`